# Regex conditionally replace

Tags: java, regex

The problem I am attempting to solve is:

> Given a string, if one or both of the first 2 chars is 'x', return the string without those 'x' chars, and otherwise return the string unchanged. This is a little harder than it looks.

```
withoutX2("xHi") → "Hi" 
withoutX2("Hxi") → "Hi"
withoutX2("Hi") → "Hi"
```

And the regex solution I have... doesn't work. I can remove the first `x` from the word, but removing the second `x` is a real pain. In this example, I want to know if it is possible to, in regex, to remove the second character without disturbing the others.

Things I've tried:

```
return str.replaceFirst("^.x", "");
```

This just simply replaces the first two letters with `""`, which not intended. I only want to replace the second character.

Comment: Match it using `^(?=x.|.x|xx).*$`

Comment: match... yes, but Kash, your solution isn't good for replacing.

Comment: @Kash this will remove also character under `.`, but OP wants to remove only `x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should allow for the first letter not being an 'x':

```
str.replaceFirst("^xx|^(.{0,1})x", "$1")
```

Comment: Doesn't work with *xxHi*: "if one **or both** of the first 2 chars is 'x'..."

Comment: what does the `$1` do in this case?

Comment: $1 is the first matching group

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't have to be solution based on regex you can use more naive way :)

Split String in two parts (if String contains more than two characters). First part will be its first two characters, second part is rest. Remove all "x" from first part and add second part to the result.

Comment: I like this answer :D, mostly cause it earned a star on codingbat.... but I wanted to use regex in a one-liner. This one was a awkward one-liner.